# RxJs How to map the child objects while returning the parent object?

Tags: foreach, rxjs, mapping

I have a complex object coming back from an API.  I am attempting to return the object with its child array of objects as an Observable.  I would like to be able to perform a function on the Content attribute of each child object in the array to transform it, but I'm slipping up on the syntax.  How can I fix this?

Here are my objects:

```
export interface ChartsViewData {
Title: string;
ItemType: number;
ChartContents: ChartContent[];
}

export interface ChartContent{
Id: number;
Content: string;
ContentType: string;
}
```

Here is the call to the API in my service, which returns the data in the parent child format, before the desired change:

```
getCharts() : Observable<ChartsViewData>{
   return this.http.get<ChartsViewData>(myUrl);
}
```

Here's what I've attempted, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
getCharts(): Observable<ChartsViewData>{
   return this.http.get<ChartsViewData>(myUrl).pipe(
    map(chartViewData => chartViewData.ChartContents.forEach((item:ChartContent) => {
      return { 
         Id: item.Id,
         Content: this.myTransformFunction(item.Content),
         ContentType: item.ContentType
      }
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `map` it using the array `map`, `forEach` just loops through it. `map` will transform the array, to do it the `forEach` way, it would have to be just `item.Content = this.myTransformFunction(item.Content);` inside of the `forEach` to overwrite it. You can decide which one you like better.

Try:

```
getCharts(): Observable<ChartsViewData>{
   return this.http.get<ChartsViewData>(myUrl).pipe(
   // Put .map and not .forEach
    map(chartViewData => chartViewData.ChartContents.map((item:ChartContent) => {
      return { 
         Id: item.Id,
         Content: this.myTransformFunction(item.Content),
         ContentType: item.ContentType
      }
   );
}
```